# How to get jasper report to load from jar file?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How do you get a compiled jasper report to load from within the jar file, instead of via a specific path on your hard drive?

My report was working fine on my machine as I had set the path to the reports with:

```
jasperReport1 = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile("/Users/admin/Documents/HCCE/Semester 2/OOP/Projects2/TestApp/src/ie/test/OMACYTDReportFinalpg1.jasper");
jasperReport2 =(JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile("/Users/admin/Documents/HCCE/Semester 2/OOP/Projects2/TestApp/src/ie/test/OMACYTDReportFinalpg2.jasper");
```

But the reports were not loading when working from the finished jar on a different computer. So I am trying to use Input stream and passing it to JasperFillManager but nothing is working - the InputStream is not finding the files. Have I the path wrong?

```
InputStream jasper1 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/ie/test/OMACYTDReportFinalpg1.jasper");
InputStream jasper2 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/ie/test/OMACYTDReportFinalpg2.jasper");
```

My original working code:

```
private void yTDReportBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    try
    {
        JasperReport jasperReport1 = null;
        JasperReport jasperReport2 = null;
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = null;
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmm-yyyy");  
        String today = formatter.format(new java.util.Date());

        //load just the compiled jasper files, to save time
        //First merge the two jasper reports into one to get page1 and page 2 in same document

        jasperReport1 = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile("/Users/admin/Documents/HCCE/Semester 2/OOP/Projects2/TestApp/src/ie/test/OMACYTDReportFinalpg1.jasper");
        jasperReport2 =(JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile("/Users/admin/Documents/HCCE/Semester 2/OOP/Projects2/TestApp/src/ie/test/OMACYTDReportFinalpg2.jasper");

        JasperPrint jp1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport1, parameters,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(ie.test.BeanFactory.getCalcs()));
        JasperPrint jp2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport2, parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(ie.test.BeanFactory.getCalcs()));

        List pages = jp2 .getPages();
        for (int j = 0; j < pages.size(); j++) {
        JRPrintPage object = (JRPrintPage)pages.get(j);
        jp1.addPage(object);
        jp1.setName(unitNameLbl.getText() + " - Financial Year To Date - " + today );

}
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp1, false);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: "+ex.getMessage() + ex);
    }
}
```

And now the changed code that is not working:

```
private void yTDReportBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    try
    {
        JasperReport jasperReport1 = null;
        JasperReport jasperReport2 = null;
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = null;
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmm-yyyy");  
        String today = formatter.format(new java.util.Date()); 

        //load just the compiled jasper files, to save time
        //First merge the two jasper reports into one to get page1 and page 2 in same document
        InputStream jasper1 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/ie/test/OMACYTDReportFinalpg1.jasper");
        InputStream jasper2 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/ie/test/OMACYTDReportFinalpg2.jasper");


        JasperPrint jp1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper1, parameters,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(ie.test.BeanFactory.getCalcs()));
        JasperPrint jp2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper2, parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(ie.test.BeanFactory.getCalcs()));

        List pages = jp2 .getPages();
        for (int j = 0; j < pages.size(); j++) {
        JRPrintPage object = (JRPrintPage)pages.get(j);
        jp1.addPage(object);
        jp1.setName(unitNameLbl.getText() + " - Financial Year To Date - " + today );

}
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp1, false);


    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: "+ex.getMessage() + ex);
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Ok update: I got the InputStreams to work by creating a new package called "reports" and using

```
InputStream jasper1 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/OMACYTDReportFinalpg1.jasper");
InputStream jasper2 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/OMACYTDReportFinalpg2.jasper");
```

And this works fine in Netbeans BUT it still won't load the files when I compile to jar!!?

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are the paths the same on both computers? Also, you probably have to escape those spaces.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the paths? I want to be able to run this report using jasper files within the jar itself. As it currently stands they are being called at their local folder location which obviously won't work on a separate machine. I thought using InputStreams would work but I keep getting a null pointer exception - seems the files can't be found!

Comment: added update see above

Comment: EDIT: I'm still getting a null pointer exception when opening the report from the jar...why is it not seeing the file? I've unzipped the jar and the reports folder is there with the report in it! Really puzzling!!!

Comment: Ok Silly mistake - it seems Netbeans doesn't care about upper and lowercase letters but the Jasper API does! There were a few upper case letters in my file name in Netbeans but when I changed them to the correct case jasper reports sees the file. But now I have a new problem - absolute paths of images embedded in the reports do not work on different machines. I need to make them relative, but not sure how.

Comment: Can you make it a command line argument for them to input the path to the report?

Answer (score 2):

you should put jasper reports in

**yourapp/src/main/resources/reports**

then you invoke that reports from class java

```
JasperReport jp = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/yourReport.jrxml"));
```

See you!

Answer (score 1):

Old topic, but could be useful.
I thing where is no **src** folder inside your jar.

```
InputStream jasper2 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ie/test/OMACYTDReportFinalpg2.jasper");
```

Where is more advanced way:
Put your jasper reports, images and other resources into jar.

Put **YourClass** inside jar file and load resources using class.getResourceAsStream() and you need to add loader extention before load resource

```
  (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject("stream or path");

  // DefaultJasperReportsContext user ExtensionsEnvironment
  ExtensionsEnvironment.setThreadExtensionsRegistry(LoaderExtention.INSTANCE);
```

The following example of loading resources

```
  public class LoaderService
    implements RepositoryService
  {
    public static final RepositoryService INSTANCE = new LoaderService();

    @Override
    public void setContext(RepositoryContext repositoryContext)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void revertContext()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream(String file)
    {
      LOGGER.fine(String.format("getInputStream('%s')", file));
      return <YourClass>.class.getResourceAsStream(file);
    }

    @Override
    public Resource getResource(String file)
    {
      LOGGER.fine(String.format("getResource('%s') not implemented", file));
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <K extends Resource> K getResource(String file, Class<K> cls)
    {
      LOGGER.fine(String.format("getResource('%s', %s)", file, cls != null? cls.getName(): null));

      try
      {
        if (cls == ReportResource.class)
        {
          InputStream resource = getInputStream(file);

          if (resource != null)
          {
            JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(resource);

            if (report != null)
            {
              ReportResource res = new ReportResource();
              res.setName(file);
              res.setReport(report);
              return (K) res;
            }
          }
        }
        else if (cls == InputStreamResource.class)
        {
          InputStream resource = getInputStream(file);

          if (resource != null)
          {
            InputStreamResource res = new InputStreamResource();
            res.setInputStream(resource);
            return (K) res;
          }
        }
      }
      catch (JRException e)
      {
      }

      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveResource(String string, Resource resource)
    {
      // TODO Implement this method
    }
  }

  public class LoaderExtention
    implements ExtensionsRegistry
  {
    public static final LoaderExtention INSTANCE = new LoaderExtention();

    @Override
    public <T extends Object> List<T> getExtensions(Class<T> cls)
    {
      ExtensionsRegistry system = ExtensionsEnvironment.getSystemExtensionsRegistry();
      List<T> services = null;

      if (system != null)
        services = system.getExtensions(cls);

      if (cls == RepositoryService.class)
      {
        List<T> servicesAll = new ArrayList<T>();

        if (services != null)
          servicesAll.addAll(services);

        servicesAll.add((T) LoaderService.INSTANCE); // Try to use system resource loaders then my
        services = servicesAll;
      }

      LOGGER.fine(String.format("getExtensions(%s) = %s", cls.getName(), services));
      return services;
    }
  }
```

I use JasperReport 5.5
Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream jasper1 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/ie/test/OMACYTDReportFinalpg1.jasper");
InputStream jasper2 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/ie/test/OMACYTDReportFinalpg2.jasper");
```

Comment: nice code. please add a short explanation to make your answer useful.

Comment: There's something in the question about using Jasper Report API.